# WPF: Is there a simple way to create a Progress Window?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, progress-bar, progress

I tried creating one, but the `BackgroundWorker` in Window1 couldn't access the `ProgressBar` in Window2 once the reportProgress was activated, because "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it".

Seems there's a lower level thread model I could use, but it also seems a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to get the `ProgressBar` disptacher.

You can access the `ProgressBar` with:

```
Window2.prograssbar.Dispatcher.Invoke(
    () => /*the code for modifying the progressbar*/ );
```

Comment: this page also helped me http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, UI controls and properties may only be activated from the UI thread. In order to change the progress bar's value from a different thread, you can add a command to the GUI thread's dispatcher queue. You can do this by passing a delegate to the `Dispatcher.Invoke()` method. See the article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into [Delegates](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html)

Comment: Except the delegate will also execute on the background thread, leaving the OP with the same problem.